# Real-Time Speech & Verbal Communication with a Mecanim Character

Tags: unity

What would be the simplest method of integrating real-time verbal communication within a **mecanim character** that is already being used in a **Unity** app/project? Something like an SDK or toolkit?

I have such a character that is animated by a motion-capture device, so the user puts on the suit and the Unity character is driven by receiving live motion data. This is the non-verbal part for research in Social Sciences & Psychology.

I tried integrating the [Virtual Human Toolkit](https://vhtoolkit.ict.usc.edu/) into my Unity app to use its **real-time speech & lip sync & facial gestures**, but their character is set up in a complicated way, so I still cannot animate it by using my motion-capture device.

So, now I am thinking what is the next best thing to do with a Unity mecanim character to make it say something, etc...?